# Javascript date formatting - one hour out due to daylight saving

Tags: javascript, date

So now, its 9:23am. I have a UTC date string that represents the current date, that looks like this `"2012-07-17T09:23:27.75"`

I want that in a date object, so I can display a nicely formatted date, so I:

```
var myDate = new Date("2012-07-17T09:23:27.75")
// Gives --> Tue Jul 17 2012 10:23:27 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

So because of daylight saving time I'm getting an hour-out issue. I can see that `myDate.getTimezoneOffset()` gives me `-60`, what's the standard / best practice way to get my date to actually reflect the current correct time? Have I just entered javascript date hell?

Comment: Dates are hell in any language, not just js.

Comment: No... i'm pretty sure it is mostly limited to just JavaScript and Java. I have never had such a difficult time with C# ever, it has always been easy with C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com). I really found it handy for such things.

```
var myDate = moment("2012-07-17T09:23:27.75");
```

Gives you a date instance in your timezone (that basically configured on your computer). Moreover momentjs has nice human friendly formattings like "a couple of seconds ago", "a month ago",...

Dates are really a hell in JS (but not only in JS). The best thing you can do is to always only transport in UTC between browser <-> server. Then on the server convert it to what time format you like, you obviously only have to be consistent. That way I managed to handle date-times properly.

Comment: Liking this lib, it's letting me parse the date without the hour-out issue, so it's a keeper :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 'T'

I was debugging some date time format issue in chrome when I found out that in console

new Date('2016-04-16T15:15:00') returns Sat Apr 16 2016 16:15:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

while

new Date('2016-04-16 15:15:00') returns Sat Apr 16 2016 15:15:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)